# How can I use cucumber/ruby to hover over an element in order to make it visible so I can click a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara

Page has products, when I hover over the image it shows the product quantity and buy now button. I want to click on quantity and buy now button after hover over.

```
driver.navigate.to('http://testsite/')   

product = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@id='recipes-inspiration-menu']")
submenu = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//li[@class='first first-child  children']")

driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[@title='placed']").click
```

Comment: Unclear what you want to do and what isn't working. Is the hover thing working? What part is missing?

Comment: I have product list on a page, how can I hover on the product and wait till browser select the quantity and click buy now button. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this (this will only work for sites that use jquery).

```
driver.execute_script('$("#element").trigger("hover")')
```